# Ruby add getters and setters without "def"?

Tags: ruby, class, setter, getter, function

I have to add getters and setters to a class Book that looks like this :

```
class Book
  def initialize (title, author, pages, year)
    @title = title 
    @author = author 
    @pages = pages 
    @year = year
  end
end
```

The problem is I am not allowed to use `def`. Is it possible somehow?
The only way I know is to use:

```
def change_name(name)
  @name = name
end
```

for a setter. I don't even know how a getter should look like.
Any help?

Comment: Out of curiosity - why are you not allowed to use `def`?

Comment: Also a getter is simply a method that returns an instance variable. For example the getter for the name instance variable could be:
(`def name  return name   end`)

Comment: @IdanArye probably because it's his homework. :)

Comment: Obviously it's my homework. I wouldn't even think not to use it :)

Comment: It's Ruby, not Rails, not a duplicate...

Comment: It's Ruby feature, thus applicable in Rails as well. Obviously it's duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby let you define simple getters/setters using the methods [`attr_accessor`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor), [`attr_reader`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Module.html#method-i-attr_reader), and [`attr_writer`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Module.html#method-i-attr_writer). In your example you can use `attr_accessor` to define both a getter and a setter for your instance variables:

```
class Book

  attr_accessor :title, :author, :pages, :year

  def initialize (title, author, pages, year)
    # same as before...
  end
end

book = Book.new('foo', 'bar', 100, 2010)
book.title
# => "foo"

book.title = 'baz'
book.title
# => "baz"
```

Calling `attr_accessor :title` is equivalent to define a couple of methods like the following:

```
def title
  @title
end

def title=(new_title)
  @title = new_title
end
```

You can find more informations about [assignment methods](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Assignment+Methods) (i.e. methods whose name end in `=`) on the Ruby documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Use `attr_accessor`:

```
class Book
  attr_accessor :title, :author, :pages, :year
  def initialize (title, author, pages, year)
    @title = title 
    @author = author 
    @pages = pages 
    @year = year
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use also `attr_accessor` (or `attr_reader` and `attr_writer`)

Answer (score 1):

Use `define_method` to define your method dynamically. In this case, directly using `attr_accessor` also should work. It will define getter and setter for you implicitly.